# How to predict the degree of the first series coefficient?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, series-expansion

*Given an expression `f` that is a function of `x` and a number `x0`, what is the least integer `n` that produces a non-zero coefficient in
`Series[f, {x, x0, n}]`?*

**[1]** For instance, here, is the answer is `n = 1`:

```
Series[Sqrt[x] (Exp[Sqrt[x]] - 1 - Sqrt[x]), {x, 0, 1}]
(*  SeriesData[x, 0, {Rational[1, 2]}, 3, 4, 2]  *)
```

**[2]** Here, it is `n = 0`:

```
Series[Sqrt[x]/(Exp[Sqrt[x]] - 1 - Sqrt[x]), {x, 0, 0}]
(*  SeriesData[x, 0, {2, Rational[-2, 3]}, -1, 1, 2]  *)
```

**[3]** Here, it is `n = -1`, lower than in the previous example, even though the order of vanishing is higher:

```
Series[x^Sqrt[2]/(Exp[Sqrt[x]] - 1 - Sqrt[x]), {x, 0, -1}]
(*  x^Sqrt[2] (SeriesData[x, 0, {2}, -2, -1, 2])  *)
```

**[4]** I'm particularly concerned about functions whose series are expensive to compute.  I would like to avoid spending a lot of time computing `Series[f, {x, 0, 0}]` only to find that `n` has to be bigger than `0`.  Likewise, it seems inefficient to compute `Series[f, {x, 0, 2}]` if `n = 0` would work.  My intuition is that this latter case might in practice not be as bad as the first case of a failed `Series`, but I may be wrong.  Here's a random example, but it doesn't show much difference between the two approaches (nor does it support my intuition):

```
ClearSystemCache[];
Series[Gamma[x^2] BesselJ[2, x]^2, {x, 0, 0}] // AbsoluteTiming
Series[Gamma[x^2] BesselJ[2, x]^2, {x, 0, 2}] // AbsoluteTiming

ClearSystemCache[];
Series[Gamma[x^2] BesselJ[2, x]^2, {x, 0, 4}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Failing an efficient answer to the opening question, my principal objective at present is to find the first nonzero series coefficient.  Example **[3]** is a type that occurs in practice.
*What is an efficient way to do determine the first nonzero series coefficient, if determining `n` exactly cannot be done quickly?*

---

Note: It is possible that the function `f` has symbolic parameters.  In my use-cases, I think numeric values may be substituted for them without annihilating the first term of the series.  In general, of course this wouldn't be true.

Comment: Can you give a closed list of all the allowed functions that you intend to consider? Say, only elementary functions + some `Gamma`, `Bessel`, and the like?. If so, it might be possible to pre-cacluate a catalog and then use it as the basis for guessing the minimal order

Comment: @yohbs From a point of view localized to my anticipated needs, combinations of elementary functions, or just those that admit series expansions, would cover most or all cases.  OTOH, having a general approach is both interesting to me and would allow for extension to cases that might prove interesting.

Comment: For `f1` the expression in the case **[1]**, `{Series[f1, {x, 0, 1}], 
 Series[Series[f1, {x, 0, 1}] // Normal, {x, 0, 1}]}` yields `{SeriesData[x, 0, {
Rational[1, 2]}, 3, 4, 2], SeriesData[x, 0, {}, 3, 3, 2]}`.  In other words, expressions with the same leading terms in their power series can yield different `Series` when taken to the same order.

Comment: Should one assume that the function values are much cheaper to calculate than the series coeffs?

Comment: @belisariusisforth  That is my thinking.  Doesn't mean it's right. But what I have in mind are all algebraic expressions in terms of standard functions.  BTW, I now think I can do it with at most two calls to `Series`; not optimal, and I was hoping for an elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

The following approach seems to work most of the time for expressions with series that can be described by a single `SeriesData`, not multiplied by other function.  This excludes case [3] in the question, to which I shall return.  Note that I arrived at the approach by trial and error, and with limited trials I may have missed a lot of errors.

Define

```
ncal1[f_, x0_, dx_] := N[Log[2, (f /. x -> x0 + 2 dx)/(f /. x -> x0 + dx)]]
ncal[f_, x0_, dx_] := Module[{ntem = ncal1[f, x0, dx]}, 
    Ceiling[Chop[ntem - Round[ntem], 10^2 dx] + Round[ntem]]]
```

`dx` should satisfy the Goldilocks criterion (not too large and not too small).
Applying these functions to the four expressions in the question, named in the obvious way,

```
ncal1[#, 0, 10^-6] & /@ {f1, f2, f3, f4}
ncal[#, 0, 10^-6] & /@ {f1, f2, f3, f4}
(* {1.5002, -0.500199, 0.414014, 2.} *)
(* {2, 0, 1, 2} *)
```

The second and fourth answers from `ncal` agree with the corresponding values in the question.  The `f1` case is anomalous, as I mentioned in an earlier comment.

```
Series[f1, {x, 0, 3}]
(* SeriesData[x, 0, {1/2, 1/6, 1/24, 1/120, 1/720}, 3, 8, 2] *)
exp = % // Normal
(* x^(3/2)/2 + x^2/6 + x^(5/2)/24 + x^3/120 + x^(7/2)/720 *)
Series[exp, {x, 0, 3}]
(* SeriesData[x, 0, {1/2, 1/6, 1/24, 1/120}, 3, 7, 2] *)
```

For some reason, the series for `f1` has one higher order term than the series of the series for `f1`.  Hence, `n = 2` is required for the power series of `f1`, but `n = 1` is sufficient for `f1` itself.  [Making Power Series Expansions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingPowerSeriesExpansions.html) discusses such behavior in a general way.

Here are more, admittedly simple, cases, for all of which the approach works.

```
{f5 = x^(-1/2) (x + x^2); nt = ncal[f5, 0, 10^-4], Series[f5, {x, 0, nt}] // Normal}
(* {1, Sqrt[x]} *)
{f6 = (1 + x + x^2); nt = ncal[f6, 0, 10^-4], Series[f6, {x, 0, nt}] // Normal}
(* {0, 1} *)
{f7 = (1/x + 1 + x + x^2); nt = ncal[f7, 0, 10^-4], Series[f7, {x, 0, nt}] // Normal}
(* {-1, 1/x *)
{f8 = Sum[x^i, {i, 3/2, 3, 1/2}]; nt = ncal[f8, 0, 10^-4], Series[f8, {x, 0, nt}] // Normal
(* {2, x^(3/2) + x^2} *)
{f9 = Sum[x^i, {i, 1/2, 2, 1/2}] + Sum[x^i, {i, 1/3, 2, 1/3}]; 
    nt = ncal[f9, 0, 10^-4], Series[f9, {x, 0, nt}] // Normal}
(* {1, x^(1/3) + Sqrt[x] + x^(2/3) + 2 x *)
{f10 = Exp[Sqrt[x]] - 1; nt = ncal[f10, 0, 10^-4], Series[f10, {x, 0, nt}] // Normal}
(* {1, Sqrt[x] + x/2 *)
{f11 = Sin[x^(2/7)]; nt = ncal[f11, 0, 10^-4], Series[f11, {x, 0, nt}] // Normal}
(* {1, x^(2/7) - x^(6/7)/6} *)
```

At first glance, obtaining more than one term in some of these expressions may seem inconsistent with the goal of the question.  However, this is the way `Series` works.  Reducing `n` from `1` to `0` in the last case, for instance, yields

```
Series[Sin[x^(2/7)], {x, 0, 0}] // Normal
(* 0 *)
```

Now, consider an ostensibly very similar problem.

```
Series[Sin[x^Sqrt[2]], {x, 0, 2}]
(* Sin[x^Sqrt[2]] *)
```

Although `Series` can handle functions of rationale powers of `x`, it cannot handle functions of irrational powers.  This seems like an unnecessary restriction.

As already noted, the approach in this answer does not work for case [3] and similar expressions containing irrational powers.  However, it can be applied in this particular instance to

```
f3/Series[f3, {x, 0, -10}][[1]]
(* 1/(-1 + E^Sqrt[x] - Sqrt[x]) *)
{nt = ncal[%, 0, 10^-4], Series[%, {x, 0, nt}] // Normal}
(* {-1, 2/x} *)
%[[2]] Series[f3, {x, 0, -10}][[1]]
(* 2 x^(-1 + Sqrt[2]) *)
```

I imagine that the OP has in mind much more complex instances of case [3], however.

**Addendum**

If computing multiple terms with fractional exponents, as in cases 8 through 11, is undesirable, the following work-around can be used.  As an example, for `f9`,

```
lcd = LCM @@ Denominator@Cases[#, Power[x, Rational[zn_, zd_]] -> zn/zd, {0, Infinity}]
    &[ft]
(nt = ncal[#, 0, 10^-4]; (Series[#, {x, 0, nt}] // Normal) /. x -> x^(1/lcd)) 
    &[ft /. x -> x^lcd]
(* x^(1/3) *)
```

This same procedure can be applied to `f1`, yielding `x^(3/2)/2` as in the question.  Alternatively, if the answer is desired in `SeriesData` form,

```
lcd = LCM @@ Denominator@Cases[#, Power[x, Rational[zn_, zd_]] -> zn/zd, {0, Infinity}]
    &[ft]
(nt = ncal[#, 0, 10^-4]; t = Series[#, {x, 0, nt}]; 
    ReplacePart[t, -1 -> lcd t[[-1]]]) &[f1 /. x -> x^lcd]
(* SeriesData[x, 0, {1/2}, 3, 4, 2] *)
```

Incidentally, just as `Series` does not accept variables raised to irrational powers, it also does not accept variables raised to approximate-number powers.

```
Series[Sin[x^N[Sqrt[2], 6]], {x, 0, 4}]
(* Sin[x^1.41421] *)
```

Comment: Thanks (+1).  I didn't get pinged when you undeleted & updated.  The numerical method seems quite good when those irrational powers are absent.  For things like `f3`, I suppose the trick is to estimate the `-10`.  I don't know if the number and order of the factors is reliable, but maybe `f3/(Series[f3, {x, 0, -10}] /. _SeriesData -> 1)` is safer.

Comment: The `-10` is simply a large negative number.  Anything large enough will do, I believe.  I have some additional  ideas, which I shall add tonight, when I have time.  My original response did not really answer your question, as I realized moments after I submitted it and then reread the question.